# Update Values in Database after getting success message using curl

Tags: php, curl

i am getting below message  after passing values in url with curl:

```
{"AddManifestDetails":[{"AuthKey":"Valid","ReturnMessage":"successful",}]
```

If **ReturnMessage** **is successful** , than i want to update values in database, i tried below code :

```
<?php

$data = 
array (
'OrderNo' => $order_id,
'AirWayBillNO' => $resultc[0]['awb'],
);

$url = "http://114.143.206.69:803/StandardForwardStagingService.svc/AddManifestDetails";

$data = json_encode($data);
$curl = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $curl_response ."\n";
$res=json_decode($curl_response);

foreach ($res->curl_response as $values) 
{
if($values->ReturnMessage=='successful')
    {
      $usql="update  do_order set tracking_id='".$resultc[0]['awb']."',shipping_name='xpress', where order_id='".$order_id."'";       
      $result=$db_handle->executeUpdate($usql);  
      echo "1";die;
    }
    else
    {
      echo $values->ReturnMessage;die;
    }
}
```

Here is full code : https://pastebin.com/EvcEY0xp

**Result** :

**Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$curl_response**

**Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

Comment: Nothing in your JSON is named `curl_response`. `var_dump($res);` or `print_r($res)` and see what you actually have

Comment: i got `object(stdClass)#4 (1) { ["AddManifestDetails"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (4) { ["AuthKey"]=> string(5) "Valid" ["ReturnMessage"]=> string(10) "successful" ["AWBNo"]=> string(14) "14104918100024" ["TokenNumber"]=> string(17) "1049_M34_26112018" } } }` @user3783243

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$res` will already contain decoded response from curl request, which will have only 1 property - `AddManifestDetails`.

Try following:

```
<?php

$data = 
array (
'OrderNo' => $order_id,
'AirWayBillNO' => $resultc[0]['awb'],
);

$url = "http://114.143.206.69:803/StandardForwardStagingService.svc/AddManifestDetails";

$data = json_encode($data);
$curl = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $curl_response ."\n";
$res=json_decode($curl_response);

if($res->AddManifestDetails[0]->ReturnMessage=='successful')
{
    $usql="update  do_order set tracking_id='".$resultc[0]['awb']."',shipping_name='xpress' where order_id='".$order_id."'";       
    $result=$db_handle->executeUpdate($usql);  
    echo "1";
    die;
}
else
{
    echo $res->AddManifestDetails[0]->ReturnMessage;
    die;
}
```

Comment: i got this reply : `Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where order_id='100433567'' at line 1 in /var/www/html/ecom1/xpress/dbcontroller.php:40 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/ecom1/xpress/dbcontroller.php(40): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'update do_orde...') #1 /var/www/html/ecom1/xpress/call4.php(124): DBController->executeUpdate('update do_orde...') #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/ecom1/xpress/dbcontroller.php on line 40`

Comment: You have incorrect SQL syntax - there is comma before WHERE. I'll update my answer.

Comment: hi, here one issue is there ,  once we click on `submit` button , its hiding, but i dont want to hide, can you please check....

Comment: There is no submit button - that question is related to how your frontend is working. You'll need to create another question with details on it. Refer to [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: before submit button was there even after clicked on it, so only i asked you, Thanks a lot, i will post new question......